# Is there any way to automate card swipe swipe scenarios of POS using selenium ao any other tool

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, sikuli

I need to automate some scenarios where card needs to be swiped in a card reading terminal device, also the card details can be feed into the device manually using the keypad on the device. Now i want to know that is it possible to somehow trigger this using an automation script or tool?